# Javascript/Django: How to handle simple search in advanced search engine?

Tags: javascript, html, django, search

I am working on advance search engine that allow multiple-layered of search(advance search) using Django but I am not sure on how to carry simple search with the search form that contain multiple search fields. E.g: In the form I got a textbox, a dropdownlist that contain several types of fruits and a submit button. The problem is when I decide just to carry a simple search by just simply enter some string into the textbox without choosing the types of fruit and leaving it as the default value `" "`, when I submitting the form it generated URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/?q=something&fruit_type=+`. Is there a way to remove the `&fruit_type=+` from the URL?

```html
<form action="/result/" method="get">
        <input type="text" id="search_box" name="q"/>
        <input type="submit" id="sbm_button" value="SEARCH" class="inputbtn"/>
        <br />
        <select name="Fruits">
            <option value=" ">Fruits</option>
            <option value="apple">Apple</option>
            <option value="orange">Orange</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Below is the view.py file:

```
def search(request):

if 'q' in request.GET:

    q = request.GET['q']
    fruit_type = request.GET['Fruits']   

    return render(request, 'result.html', {
                                           'query' : q,
                                           'fruit' : fruit_type,
                                          })
```

It will return the q and fruit_type to result.html with the generated URL which had mentioned above. Is there a way to ignore the `Fruits` dropdownlist within the form(submitting the form and ignoring the dropdownlist)? Is it possible to do this in Javascript? Thank you.